# Echo ACF oEmbed field in custom tab

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have added a custom tab to WooCommerce single product page, and I am trying to echo the ACF standard output to display an oEmbed video.

The tab is added successfully, but I'm struggling with the function adding content to the tab.

```
syntax error, unexpected 'virtual_video_tour' (T_STRING), expecting ';' or ','
```

I have also tried the process of 'RETURN' then 'ECHO' but still failed.

Could you please point me in the direction of where and what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_virtual_tour_tab' );
function woo_virtual_tour_tab( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['virtualtour_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Video Tour', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 50,
        'callback'  => 'woo_virtual_tour_tab_content'
    );
    return $tabs;
}

function woo_virtual_tour_tab_content () {
echo '<div class="embed-container">
        <?php the_field('virtual_video_tour'); ?>
        </div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<?php` is open...

In other words, you didn't close the echo statement before you output the field, or tried to use `<?php` again.

```
function woo_virtual_tour_tab_content () {
    echo '<div class="embed-container">';
        the_field('virtual_video_tour');
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Or you can use concatenation like this:

```
function woo_virtual_tour_tab_content () {
    echo '<div class="embed-container">'. the_field('virtual_video_tour'). '</div>';
}
```

Comment: oh, Gotcha! I'm with you now. Thank you Howard.